# R: scope of local/global variables

Tags: r, function

I have two R chunks as follows:

```
getDetails<-function(files){
    read.csv(filenames)
}

filenames<-list.files("data/", pattern=".csv", full.names=T)
df<-lapply(filenames, getDetails)
```

In the function, by mistake even when I have mentioned `filenames` variable instead of `files`, I don't get any error. Is there any way to make R warn about this?

Thanks.

Comment: See `codetools::findGlobals` and http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#dynamic-lookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`environment(getDetails) = parent.env(environment(getDetails))` is a way to remove the global scope. This works for me. Only problem is, this has to be done for every function that I write.